# LibGDX: Use same TextureAtlas twice or use two different TextureAtlases

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm migrating my native Android game to libGDX. That's why I use flipped graphics. Apparently `NinePatch`es can't be flipped. (They are invisible or [look strange](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=6193&p=80344&hilit=NinePatch#p80344).)

What would be more efficient:

- use one big `TextureAtlas` containing all graphic files and load it twice (flipped and unflipped) or
- use one big `TextureAtlas` for the flipped graphic files and a second small one for the NinePatch graphics?

Type A:

```
public static TextureAtlas atlas, atlas2;

public static void load() {
    // big atlas (1024 x 1024)
    atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("game.atlas"), true); 
    // find many AtlasRegions here

    // Same TextureAtlas. Loaded into memory twice?
    atlas2 = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("game.atlas"), false);
    button = ninepatch.createPatch("button");
    dialog = ninepatch.createPatch("dialog");
}
```

Type B:

```
public static TextureAtlas atlas, ninepatch;

public static void load() {
    // big atlas (1024 x 1024)
    atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("game.atlas"), true); 
    // find many AtlasRegions here

    // small atlas (128 x 64)
    ninepatch = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("ninepatch.atlas"), false); 
    button = ninepatch.createPatch("button");
    dialog = ninepatch.createPatch("dialog");
}
```

Comment: Either way, you'll end up with a lot of texture swaps which could potentially degrade performance quite a bit. Any reason you can't just flip your assets before you generate the texture atlas?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I think flipping all png files is a good option (if I can automate this with a script).

Comment: That was easy (on Linux with imagemagick installed): `for file in mdpi/*.png ; do convert $file -flip mdpi_flipped/$file ; done`

Answer (score 0):

now I do not have time to test, I expound the idea, but I think it can work, is based on a texture, not texture atlas for simplicity.

```
short metadata = 2;

Texture yourTextureMetadata = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(metaDataTexture));

int width  = yourTextureMetadata.getWidth()   - metadata;
int height = yourTextureMetadata.getHeight()  - metadata;

TextureRegion yourTextureClean = new TextureRegion(yourTextureMetadata, 
                                             1, 1, width, height);
```

I assume that metadata has a size of two, now I do not remember, sorry

the idea would take, the largest texture, with metadata and then cut them to have clean on the other side so that you can turn around, I hope to work.

for texturealtas would similar, findRegions and cut metadata and save them without metadata

On the other hand, note that you have static textures, and I think when android change of context, your application to another application, and then back to yours application, you can give errors visualization, your images can black display

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't downvote it. But I don't understand what you mean. Is it about cutting the 1-pixel-border of .9.png files? I think that happens automatically.

Comment: @MaxGyver ahh now I understood, your question, of course, is that my English is very bad, thought that quiras have a texture with metadata and one without, sorry for the poor response

Comment: No problem. And concerning the static textures: yes, I know that I have to dispose them. Maybe it's easier to create an instance of my Assets class.